# tcp/ip connection with anonymous client IP

Tags: tcp

I'm creating a tcp/ip system using VS2010,C#, I'm going to setup a server program in my Server PC (win2008R2), I've opened port 2020 and now I can send data to this port using my GSM/GPRS modems, I have a small problem relates to clients ip address, in my server I should specify an IP address for listening, I have several modems which will be used as my clients, they may be turned off/on, so I don't know anything about their IP, how can I know IP port to listen for? I should use IPAddress.Any? what are my options?
I've used a test server program which can receive data from any client IP address, how does this program do so? how can it detect client IP?
is there any sample or tutorial showing this?
thanks

Comment: Please share code to start listening on port 2020. I am trying to connect via gprs on my SIM900 and can connect to web servers. Let me know if you have the desktop application for it. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using TcpListener, and are referring to the IPAddress parameter to the constructor.  That isn't a client IP; it's the server's own IP address that you want to listen on.  You really only need to specify it if the server has multiple network interfaces (or multiple IPs on a single interface) and you only want to accept connections on one of them.  If you want to bind to all of the server's IPs, then use IPAddress.Any.

Check out the Remarks on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6z86e63.aspx for some more special cases for those parameters.

Comment: yes I think you are right, I made a mistake, but how should I set this Ip address? I should use 127.0.0.1, or 192.168.x.y or real IP address of my server? the test program displayed real IP address of my server when installed and run on my server, what should I specify now? thanks

Comment: Edited to elaborate some more on the use of the IpAddress parameter